# protected variable from super class not visible from subclass in different package

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two classes in different packages as follows
This is the base class in package library.

```
package library;

public class Book{

    public int varPublic;
    protected int varProtected;
    private int varPrivate;
    int varDefault;
}
```

and this is the subclass in the package building.

```
package building;

import library.Book;

public class StoryBook extends Book {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Book book = new Book();
        book.varPublic = 10;
        book.varProtected = 11;


    }

}
```

my understanding is that the variable "var.Protected" should be visible in the class StoryBook but i am getting an error. I have tried to execute this code from eclipse and command-prompt.

could anyone please look into this

Comment: this.varProtected =11; //this would work fine...

Comment: issue is the same but both the codes are different. In the other post he is using this keyword to assign a protected variable inside a constructor. But i am trying to access the protected variable directly with reference to the object. i am a beginner in java programming and this code i have written does not do what is described in the java tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes in other packages that are subclasses of the declaring class can only access their own inherited `protected` members.

```
public class StoryBook extends Book {
    public StoryBook() {
        System.out.println(this.variable); // this.variable is visible
    }
}
```

... but not other objects' inherited `protected` members.

```
public class StoryBook extends Book {
    public StoryBook() {
        System.out.println(this.variable); // this.variable is visible
    }

    public boolean equals(StoryBook other) {
        return this.variable == other.variable; // error: StoryBook.variable is not visible
    }
}
```

Also take a took at this article

**[Why a protected member of a superclass can't be accessed from a subclass by using a superclass' reference?](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/why-a-protected-member-of-a-superclass-cant-be-accessed-from-a-subclass-by-using-a-superclass-reference/109)**